# How is PAM checking the user password in unprivileged processes?

Tags: pam, non-root-user, setuid, shadow

PAM manages to check the user password, when called from unprivileged screen-lockers. E.g.:

- [Password for GNU screen lockscreen command?](https://serverfault.com/a/169926/133475)
- https://github.com/google/xsecurelock

I can't find any SUID-root binary in the `screen` package on Fedora 26, but the `lockscreen` command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>) still works. I can't see any the Makefile in `xsecurelock` setting SUID root anywhere either.

I'm confused.  How does this work?  My user does not have read access to `/etc/shadow`. I am not using the OpenWall [pam_tcb](http://www.openwall.com/tcb/) for per-user shadow files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the binaries installed by pam, it includes `unix_checkpwd`.

> unix_chkpwd is a helper program for the pam_unix module that verifies the password of the current user. It also checks password and account
>          expiration dates in shadow. It is not intended to be run directly from the command line and logs a security violation if done so.
>
> It is typically installed setuid root or setgid shadow.
>
> The interface of the helper - command line options, and input/output data format are internal to the pam_unix module and it should not be
>          called directly from applications.